AWS SNS SMS doesn't work on eu-west-2 but works on eu-west-1
I have a simple SNS topic with an SMS subscription in the eu-west-2 region.
For some reason I cannot ever receive the sandbox verification code when I add my number, for this, I have tried multiple different phone numbers from different network carriers and it's the same every time, the message is marked as sent but I never receive anything.
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "4ad25859-3541-5587-b51c-07d978382542",
        "timestamp": "2024-10-09 09:22:01.478"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "phoneCarrier": "O2",
        "mnc": 10,
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+44XXXXXXXXXX",
        "priceInUSD": 0.03888,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 234,
        "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone carrier",
        "dwellTimeMs": 26,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 3189
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}

as it can be seen in the CloudWatch logs it says that it was delivered
strangely enough when I switch to eu-west-1 I receive the sandbox verification SMS instantly.
I have raised this as a ticket with AWS, but they didn't offer any help, and I have seen a few similar posts on their forums with no resolution.
I was wondering if anybody has any fix for this.

I've hit the same issue recently, with SMS refusing to send, and this is after the code was working fine for 2 years.
Everything looks good and I receive a Success status, but nothing gets delivered to the phone.
After much back and forth with AWS it turns out that a proper registered Sender ID is now required in the UK (you can register one of these in "AWS End User Messaging > SMS" as opposed to "Amazon SNS").
For the first time, I was able to successfully send an SMS via the console.
I am now trying to update my code so that it sends a request through the correct channel, picking up the registered Sender ID.

Same happened here, can't send msg to Sweden from eu-central-1 but works well with us-east-1. No errors either, work from console. Even though Sweden doesn't require senderID registration.
